# Extract value/s from JSON string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this code trying to extract the first (or both) "ZoneId" values from the below JSON string:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {"EntityId": 8628428,"Subscriptions": [{"ZoneName": "Customer Secure Zone","ZoneId": "51",},{"ZoneName": "Wholesaler Secure Zone","ZoneId": "3573",},]}}');
alert(obj.SecureZoneSubscriptionList[0].ZoneId);
```

I have looked at other similar versions of code that do exactly this and work, but when I apply it to my situation is fails to work?
Would love to know what I'm doing wrong (this is the first time I've worked with JSON and also still a novice with jQuery)... would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: and the error you get is....?  let me guess, `obj is null`?

Comment: To add, FireBug reports the following error: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
 var obj = {
     "SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {
         "EntityId": 8628428,
         "Subscriptions": [{
             "ZoneName": "Customer Secure Zone",
             "ZoneId": "51",
             },
         {
             "ZoneName": "Wholesaler Secure Zone",
             "ZoneId": "3573",
             }, ]
     }
 };

 alert(obj.SecureZoneSubscriptionList.Subscriptions[0].ZoneId);
```

Note that the 'Subscriptions' is where your array is ... not SecureZoneSubscriptionList

**Edit** Question guy asked another question:

```
  var obj = {
      "SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {
      "EntityId": 8628428,
           "Subscriptions": [{
                "ZoneName": "Customer Secure Zone",
                "ZoneId": "51",
           } ]
      }
 };

 alert(obj.SecureZoneSubscriptionList.Subscriptions[0].ZoneId);
```

This would work for 1 element still.

```
 alert(obj.SecureZoneSubscriptionList.Subscriptions.length);
```

The above will tell you the length of your element.  You can do some conditional statements to `if / else if / else` to work with it ...

Comment: Hi, again. I've run into an issue with this. Sometimes my JSON data will have only one subscription data set and sometimes it will have 2. When I have code to extract 'Subscription[0]' and Subscriptions[1] the script will error if there is only one subscription data set present. Can I just retrieve any/all "ZoneId" values that may exist? in other words, can I simply **not** define a specific index to look in (please excuse any incorrect terminology)

Comment: Yes, the `.length` combined with `if / else` statements has done the trick. Thank you, your a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it isn't a typo, your JSON isn't valid (you have a lot of commas that are not supposed to be there).  [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)  is your friend, I recommend you use it when you run into issues like this.

```
{
    "SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {
        "EntityId": 8628428,
        "Subscriptions": [
            {
                "ZoneName": "Customer Secure Zone",
                "ZoneId": "51",

            },
            {
                "ZoneName": "Wholesaler Secure Zone",
                "ZoneId": "3573",

            },

        ]
    }
}
```

---

Correct:

```
{
    "SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {
        "EntityId": 8628428,
        "Subscriptions": [
            {
                "ZoneName": "Customer Secure Zone",
                "ZoneId": "51"
            },
            {
                "ZoneName": "Wholesaler Secure Zone",
                "ZoneId": "3573"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of extra commas in there and extra commas are not supported in the JSON spec. Eg: `"ZoneId": "3573",},]}` (before the bracket and brace). You'll have difficulty so long as those remain.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've got a syntax error in the JavaScript string somewhere, I'll assume it's some bad copy paste.
2. Given the stricture, you'll want to be looking for `obj.SecureZoneSubscriptionList.Subscriptions[0].ZoneId` - note the `.Subscriptions` in there